# input type file - not getting border bottom line

Tags: html, css

I'm using Input type file. But I'm not getting border bottom line for that. I tried using class but it also didn't work
Here is my code:

`<input type="file" id="Input" style="float: right; " accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. can you please include a html and makes a [code snippet or minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead,

```css
#Input{
  border-bottom:2px solid #00cc00;
}
```

```html
 <input type="file" id="Input" style="float: right; " accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question, you should try this;

```
<div class="my_input">
<input type="file" id="Input" style="float: right; " accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
</div>
```

And in styles;

```
.my_input {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```